# Using a ForEach loop to reverse csv files

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

What I need to do is to take a number of text files (csv, all in one directory) and create files where the entire output is reversed line by line, but keeping the header at the top instead of ending up at the bottom.

I am able to take one file (by name) and copy the first line and create a new file with just that line in it.  Then I take the original file minus the first line, read it into an array and reverse it.  I then append that to the file that only has the header.  It works fine, except for the output name, which I'd like to be `[file-REV.csv]` but so far I've only gotten to `[file.csv-REV]`...

So, once I had that working, I thought it was time to have the program find all of the `csv`'s in the directory and loop through them, creating a reverse file for each.

This is what I have so far:

```
cd c:\users\$([Environment]::UserName)\working

$Path = "c:\users\$([Environment]::UserName)\working\"

ForEach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv) {
    Get-Content $file  -totalcount 1 | Set-Content .\$file-REV.csv
    $flip = (get-content | select -Skip 1)
    [array]::Reverse($flip)
    $flip | add-content "$file-REV.csv"
 }
```

Here is the message I receive when executing the script:

> cmdlet Get-Content at command pipeline position 1
>
> Supply values for the following parameters:
>
> Path[0]:

I've tried to put in the entire path `Get-Content -Path c:\users\jmurphy\working\` and then it complains that it can't find the entire path.

Comment: The first thing I recommend is to look at the output of [`Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Detailed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Get-Help Get-Content -Detailed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content). You will find that the `Get-Help` cmdlet is one of the most useful when learning how to use PowerShell.

Comment: ignoring potential other problems give `Get-Content` the file name from the loop you made `$flip = (get-content $file | select -Skip 1)`. _c:\users\jmurphy\working_ is a folder .. not a file.

Comment: Thank you both.  I'll start with your suggestions.  I didn't even know about Get-Help (MS-man is what it sounds like).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things. First you are defining the folder to work in a variable, so use that in the `Get-ChildItem`. (I change the name to `$Folder` out of habit because `$Path` is already used variable in the Environment scope. Also `$env:` is a quicker way to read the variables out of the Environment scope.).

```cs
$Folder = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\working\"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter *.csv
```

Second, you'll just want to use the `Fullname` property from what's returned from `Get-ChildItem` because that's the full path of each file.

```cs
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
```

So you'll want to use that full path to the file in your `Get-Content`

```cs
Get-Content $File.Fullname -totalcount 1 | Set-Content .\$($file.Basename)-REV.csv
```

and you'll want to use `$File` again as the path to the file when you call `Get-Content` again:

```cs
$Flip = (Get-Content $File.Fullname | Select -Skip 1)
```

`Basename` is the property from `Get-Childitem` with just the filename without the extension. You can force an evaluation of a property of a variable inside double quotes by enclosing in `$()`.

```cs
$Flip | Add-Content "$($file.Basename)-REV.csv"
```

All together the script should look like this:

```cs
$Folder = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\working\"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter *.csv
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    Get-Content $File.Fullname -totalcount 1 | Set-Content .\$($file.Basename)-REV.csv
    $Flip = (Get-Content $File.Fullname | select -Skip 1)
    [array]::Reverse($Flip)
    $Flip | Add-Content "$($file.basename)-REV.csv"
}
```

Comment: Hey Ben, excellent answer! You should remove the trailing slashes in your paths so that StackOverflow Syntax Highlighting works correctly instead of interpreting the entire code block as a string. (The backslash character is an escape character in other languages like C#)

Comment: @Bluecakes No need really. Look at the edit. when this happens I use `<!-- language-all: lang-cs -->` as to not change the source too much. It's not perfect but is a little better

Comment: While its not super costly either way why not just read the file in once and split accordingly. Also i don't think you need to use the fullname property exclusively Just `$file`  would work.

Comment: Ben, thank you so much for the breakdown.  When I ran it, it 'sort of' worked.  I got all the reverse files, but there was an error for each file run and the files had no headers.  This was the error:

Comment: <<Set-Content : Could not open the alternate data stream 
'\Users\jmurphy\working\All_fields.csv-REV.csv' of the file 'C:\users\jmurphy\working\C'.
At line:4 char:39
+     Get-Content $File -totalcount 1 | Set-Content ./$File-REV.csv}
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\jmurphy\working\C:String) [Set-C 
   ontent], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterFileNotFoundError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com 
   mands.SetContentCommand>>

Comment: I knew I wasn't trying to write something to an NTFS alt stream, so I just kept thinking about it.  It turned out to be the .\ before the $file-Rev.csv.

Once you had the $File.Fullname used, adding the .\ before an entire path ended with it believing I was looking for an alternate string.  Got rid of the .\ and everything is beautiful!  Also read http://www.computerworld.com/article/2879205/data-center/powershell-for-beginners-scripts-and-loops.html which is a dead simple article about variables and loops.

Thanks to everyone for their help.  I will try to help others as I learn more.

Comment: @JoeMurphy If an answer satisfied your question it is best practice to accept it. As you noticed the `Add-Content` line and the `Set-Content` line pointed to different paths. I have since edited that.

Answer (score 0):

Joe, you are doing great at learning PowerShell. You just need to harness the power of object orientation a little more.

You already know that Get-ChildItem will return an object about the file(s). What you need to know are the members included in that object. Use Get-Member to find that out.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem .\t.csv
$file | Get-Member
```

Once you find an interesting member, see what its value is.

```
$file.Name
$file.Extension
$file.BaseName
```

From this, you can construct a new file name.

```
$newFilename = $file.Basename + '-REV' + $file.Extension
```

Put this before the Get-Content line. Then use $newFilename with Add-Content.